# One-Sided Notion of Topological Closure

Tags: general-topology, monotone-functions, measurable-functions, semicontinuous-functions, sorgenfrey-line

Has the following notion already been studied?  I am really stuck on a problem that seems to require some general results concerning this:

Let $A$ be a subspace of $\mathbb{R}$.  Define an operation called 'left closure' to be $lcl(A)$, that sends $A$ to the subset

$\lbrace x \in \mathbb{R} : \text{ there exist } y_n \in A \text{ s.t. } y_n \leq x$ $\forall$ $n \text{ and } y_n \rightarrow x \rbrace$

So this is like the left-sided closure of $A$; it contains all the points that $A$ 'converges to' from the left.  We can define $rcl(A)$ similarly.  I am wondering what the best way to think about these objects is.  There seem like too many choices.  In my particular situation, I am dealing with topologically unpleasant objects (uncountable unions of pw-disjoint Cantor Sets), so anything that is well suited to such applications is preferable.

To ask more of a question than a reference request, what can be said about infinite unions of Cantor sets, either countably or uncountable?  Anything that falls out of the definition?

The problem that I am especially interested in is this: If $C$ is the union of an uncountable collection of pw disjoint Cantor Sets $C_\alpha$, is it possible to apply an order to the indices taking values from $[0,1]$ so that the union of $C_\alpha, 0 \leq \alpha \leq \alpha_0$ is right-closed in $C$ for any fixed $\alpha_0$?  That is to say that any collection of sets 'to the left' of some $C_{\alpha_0}$ doesn't accumulate to one of its points from the right.

Thanks!  I tagged some topics that seem most likely to contribute, but if anyone has other suggestions, then that would also be helpful.

Comment: I don't understand the question. What do you mean by "what can be said about infinite unions of Cantor sets"? What are "these objects"? What would "fall out" of which definition?

Comment: What are some rules for how families of Cantor Sets can left-converge onto each other?  For example, is it possible to place an order on an uncountable collection of Cantor Sets so that only predecessors can converge from the left onto a point of some fixed Cantor Set?  For example, see this problem.  https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2872483/uncountable-collections-of-arcs-in-the-plane-with-prescribed-properties

Comment: Yeah. I still don't get it. If you want anyone to answer the question, I think you need to make it more precise.

Comment: Suppose instead of Cantor set, you say "Uncountable  nowhere-dense perfect set". Do you really want $C$ to be a collection of isometric copies of "the" Cantor set?

Comment: No no, not isometric copies.  Just topological homeomorphs.